# Installed Firefox Beta and now Bing is default search engine in location bar

Tags: search, firefox, web-browser, google, search-engine

I updated from Firefox 31 to Firefox Beta (32) and when I now do a search in the location bar (the big one to the left) I get results from Bing.

How do I change this back to Google?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it to Google in Firefox Preferences. Go to Search tab and select Google as default search engine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

about:config

browser.search.defaultenginename

Answer (score 0):

In the search bar (not the the address bar), you can choose which search engine you prefer.

It looks like this on FF31 when you click on the small arrow, a pop up window will open.

[image]